# Dynamically assign web service endpoint urls

Tags: java, web-services, websphere

Our business process invokes an external web service, we may need to change the web service URLs for different environments. 

**For Example:** 

For DEV server we will have one web service end point URL where as for PROD there will be a different one. So in this case we should be able to set the endpoint urls dynamically depending on the environment so that we do not need to change our EAR file for each environment.

How do we assign an end point URL dynamically to a web service in WebSphere Server?

Please help me because i am beginer for WebService.

Comment: What web service client API are you using?

Comment: Agree with @McDowell. The solution depends on the Web Services API you're using. Easiest would be if you use JAX-WS 2.1 or later.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring (or can use Spring) then I would suggest using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer. Also please take a look at [this post](http://www.developer.com/java/ent/article.php/3811931/Enterprise-Deployment-Environment-Configuration-with-Java-Spring.htm)
 for setting up different deployment environment settings.

Comment: Can a Mavan based solution be considered in your case? Because you can use Maven's resource filtering feature, along with profiles to generate a properties file for each deployment environment like dev, test, staging, production etc.

Answer (score 0):

Call [javax.xml.ws.Service.setHandlerResolver](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Service.html#setHandlerResolver%28javax.xml.ws.handler.HandlerResolver%29).  Pass an implementation that returns an implementation of [LogicalHandler](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/LogicalHandler.html).  In [handleMessage](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/Handler.html#handleMessage%28C%29), check [MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/MessageContext.html#MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY) to update [ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/ws/BindingProvider.html#ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY).